# How to center text vertically in HTML using CSS only

Tags: html, css, text, center

I have a very simple HTML. Due to some limitations, I cannot modify the HTML content. I want to center the text vertically only using CSS.

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>

    <body>
        <div>Oops, the webpage is currently not available.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the size of the HTML can be variable.

In addition, if the text cannot be displayed in one line, it should be broken into multiple lines.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think vertical-align only works for content which is in a table. For your simple page you could put the content in a table instead of a div to avoid this problem.

There are some workarounds, see http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: The brave new world of CSS. You have to use `position: absolute` or `line-height` to do something as complex as vertically align some content. (Not criticizing you @matschie, just not understanding what the committee that put together this standard was *thinking*)

Comment: Well really IE's fault otherwise using `display: table` would work fine.

Comment: "line-height" has a problem actually. if the text is too long, the rest of them is out of the visible area. 

Anyway, I have given up. I use a table instead.

Comment: Pekka I totally agree with you, those solutions are not nice but I cant really think of anything else right now.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>
            body {height:100%}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="height:100%;">
            <div style="position:relative;top:50%;text-align:center">Oops, the webpage is currently not available.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <head>...
       <style type="text/css">
           div{
               width: 300px;
               height: 300px;
               border: solid blue;
               display: table-cell;
               vertical-align: middle;
           }
       </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>This works fine!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can skip width, height, border attributes. They are used just to show visually the task.

Comment: Though `table-cell` is not supported by IE <= 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .vertical {
                margin: 0;
                background: yellow;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-right: -50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="vertical">
         Centered
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
.text-tag{

    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25%;
}
```

And apply "text-tag" to the text you want to center.