# Problems having my text centered vertically u_u

Tags: html, text, center, vertical-scrolling

So you see, I'm having a big problem here. I've already tried tons of solutions, but none have been useful to me. I'm making a custom tooltip, and I'm trying to get the text shown inside it gets vertically centered, but I haven't been able to.

```
    .tooltip {
    display:none;
    background:transparent url(slides/tooltip_img.png);
font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:16px;
    height:157px;
    width:149px;
    color:#eee;
text-align:center;
line-height:20px;
    }
```

And this here is how I'm trying to make it center vertically:

```
    <div id="tooltip" style="height:62px;margin-left:46px;margin-top:102px;vertical-align:middle">
    <img src="supahsource.png" title="Tooltip info"/>
```

Anyway, I don't get the result I'm trying, can anybody help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to use the search function next time.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048541/vertical-text-center-in-div

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943234/how-to-center-text-vertically-in-html-using-css-only

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` only works with Table elements. Try using `position: absolute` and if you really want to use `vertical-align`, use `display: table-cell;` on the block you wish to vertically align.

Comment: `vertical-align` applies to inline level and table-cell elements.

Comment: You're right. I mispoke. `vertical-align` is good for inline elements. So you could vertically align the picture within a paragraph tag, but not the text within the paragraph tag.